# How to equally make "steps flow" with bootstrap or with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make alignment for "steps flow" with content and at the same time it should be responsive with content

What I've done so far:

[image: What I've done so far]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Here's my code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto; 
}
.text-msg { margin:20px 0; display:block; clear:both; text-align:justify;}
.progressbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: step;
   clear:both;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
        <li class="active">login</li>
        <li>choose interest</li>
        <li>add friends</li>
        <li>View map</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vvvx36hj/2/)

Comment: Just give left and right padding to the paragraph

Comment: Just try my jquery option, it was working

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i have made some changes in `CSS` to achieve what you want but i dont suggest the way you are using the active class and i know this is a sample code so i dont complain much, here is some CSS i have added

```
ul li:first-child:before{
  margin-left:0;
}
ul li:first-child{
  text-align:left;
}
ul li:last-child:before{
  margin-right:0;
}
ul li:last-child{
  text-align:right;
}
```

this to css

 here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1f8a0vt4/

Comment: Yeah i have seen that i recommend you to add line separately and numbers separately not as pseudo elements then you can have some query script for line colouring i have done same for my website so i am suggesting this i lost link with similar example if i find it i'll update in comment.. Thank You

Comment: http://azmind.com/bootstrap-wizard-tutorial-new-step/ here is the link of similar form which i have used and in that form you use my css to align progress bar end to end

Answer (score 0):

**I did by using jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setWidth();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
setWidth();
});
   function setWidth(){
 var listWidth = $(".progressbar li:first-child").width();  
    $('.text-msg').css('padding-left',(listWidth/2)-15);
    $('.text-msg').css('padding-right',(listWidth/2)-15);
    }
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto; 
}
.text-msg { margin:20px 0; display:block; clear:both; text-align:justify;}
.progressbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: step;
   clear:both;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <ul class="progressbar">
            <li class="active">login</li>
            <li>choose interest</li>
            <li>add friends</li>
            <li>View map</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="text-msg">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: it can be support in responsive also.

Comment: almost your solution is right but when we resize it will trough an error  setWidth not defined

Comment: Run you snippet & then make it full page you can see it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/u3yp1umd/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function calcWidth(){
    var calcWidth = parseFloat($("li.active").first().width()/2) -15 ;  
    $('.text-msg').css({
      'margin-left': calcWidth,
      'margin-right': calcWidth
    });
  }
    
  calcWidth();
    
  $(window).resize(function(){
    calcWidth();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto; 
}
.text-msg { margin:20px 0; display:block; clear:both; text-align:justify;}
.progressbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: step;
   clear:both;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">login</li>
    <li>choose interest</li>
    <li>add friends</li>
    <li>View map</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="text-msg">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @MaheswaranS Yes, to overcome the problem in your code.